# Redirect to path according to params using named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def destroy
    @project = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@project)
    respond_to do |format|
            format.html { params[:page]? (redirect_to "#{params[:page]}_path") :           (redirect_to @project ) }
            format.js 
    end
end
```

in above code if i pass params[:page] = "dashboard" then it should redirect to dashboard_path  but currently it redirects to localhost:3000dashboard_path

i know where is the problem ("#{params[:page]}_path" returns a string rather than a path)  but i want the solution bcoz i dont know how to fix this.

thanks a lot.

Comment: please dont end up using `eval`

Comment: sorry i did't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
redirect_to send("#{params[:page]}_path")
```

or full version is

```
format.html { params[:page] ? redirect_to(send("#{params[:page]}_path")) : redirect_to(@project) }
```

Comment: yaa thanks it worked but can u  please explain it because i thing "#{params[:page]}_path" is still a string so how it redirects to string path

Comment: @RahulSingh it is a sting, but it is being passed as a param to a method. You're probably thinking it is a method call.

Comment: @NoahClark ok got it but what happens if pass it like this send("/dashboard"), will it still redirect to that or it is an error

Comment: you can just try to do it and will see. Method [send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) accept a symbol (or string) and a list of params. Symbol will be called as method name and params will be passed to name as arguments

Answer (score 1):

Such dependency on param is unnecessary in my opinion.

It's you who write the controller, it's also you who define such query string in previous page.

So, why not `redirect_to dashboard_path` directly if that's all of your desired logic?

Comment: no i have many params values like params[:page] = "dashboard" so dashboard_path if params[:page] = "watch_list" then to watch_lists_path and if there is no params then project_path